# laravel hosting on wamp

Tags: php, laravel-5, wamp, shared-hosting

I have followed a tutorial here @ https://github.com/petehouston/laravel-deploy-on-shared-hosting on how to install laravel application on a shared hosting  and also here @ https://medium.com/laravel-news/the-simple-guide-to-deploy-laravel-5-application-on-shared-hosting-1a8d0aee923e
but have come to a difficult when I visit the localhost here is the 
error dump please help
```

```
FatalErrorException in Encrypter.php line 100:
Call to undefined function openssl_decrypt()
in Encrypter.php line 100
at FatalErrorException->__construct() in HandleExceptions.php line 133
at HandleExceptions->fatalExceptionFromError() in HandleExceptions.php line 118
at HandleExceptions->handleShutdown() in HandleExceptions.php line 0
at Encrypter->decrypt() in EncryptCookies.php line 95
at EncryptCookies->decryptCookie() in EncryptCookies.php line 76
at EncryptCookies->decrypt() in EncryptCookies.php line 59
at EncryptCookies->handle() in Pipeline.php line 136
at call_user_func_array:{C:\wamp\cruitement\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php:136}() in Pipeline.php line 136
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}() in Pipeline.php line 32
at call_user_func:{C:\wamp\cruitement\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php:32}() in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}() in Pipeline.php line 103
at call_user_func:{C:\wamp\cruitement\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php:103}() in Pipeline.php line 103
at Pipeline->then() in Router.php line 726
at Router->runRouteWithinStack() in Router.php line 699
at Router->dispatchToRoute() in Router.php line 675
at Router->dispatch() in Kernel.php line 246
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}() in Pipeline.php line 52
at call_user_func:{C:\wamp\cruitement\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php:52}() in Pipeline.php line 52
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}() in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 44
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle() in Pipeline.php line 136
at call_user_func_array:{C:\wamp\cruitement\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php:136}() in Pipeline.php line 136
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}() in Pipeline.php line 32
at call_user_func:{C:\wamp\cruitement\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php:32}() in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}() in Pipeline.php line 103
at call_user_func:{C:\wamp\cruitement\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php:103}() in Pipeline.php line 103
at Pipeline->then() in Kernel.php line 132
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter() in Kernel.php line 99
at Kernel->handle() in index.php line 54
at {main}() in index.php line 0
```

can any spot what i missing please thanks in advance

Comment: I think you need to check you shared hosting php version that either it is supported or not.

Comment: Please enable the php_openssl extension in the WAMP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the php_openssl extension is not enabled

If you are running code from the command line then you need to edit the `php.ini` file in `wamp\bin\php\php{version}\php.ini`

If you are doing this from within the browser you need to check the `php.ini` file used by Apache (they are different)

```
left click wampmanager->PHP->php.ini
```

to open the file in your defauilt editor

In both files check for this line

```
extension=php_openssl.dll
```

Make sure it does not have a `#` commenting the line out.

Comment: checked everything the extensions all of them seems to be enabled